# Конвертировать .py - > .apk Python файл обычный скрипт!

Tags: python, exe, apk, конвертация

Мне нужно обычный скрипт на Python конвертировать в apk!
Считайте код такой:
q = input()
print(q)
Может как-нибудь сначала .py - > .exe, а потом в apk?

Answer (score 0):

Конвертировать из exe в apk вещь практически невозможная. Насчёт консольных приложений не знаю, но можно скомпилировать в apk kivy с помощью [python for Android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) или pygame с помощью [Pygame Subset for Android](http://devhead.ru/read/pygame-na-android). Если нужно просто запустить, то есть Pydroid3.

Comment: то есть чтобы запустить файл .py нужно приложение на телефоне Pydroid3?

Comment: @harik Да, через приложение открываешь файл и запускаешь его, как в обычном редакторе кода.

Comment: Потянет ли это приложение большие библиотеки? Например threading requests vk api?

Comment: @harik не сказал бы, что эти библиотеки большие, так что "потянет".